# Is Hejinian saying that there is no one privileged way of reading any text?

Tags: theory

You can read about the so called l=a=n=g=u=a=g=e poet's rejection of closure [here](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/articles/69401/the-rejection-of-closure) (it's short). Is she saying that an open reading, which is what the text is about, theorizes on, **does not privilege different goals in reading**, e.g. working out whodunit?

Hejinian is explicitly saying that there are many readings of an open text, so I just wondered if each different method, way, of reading a text is equally viable, if they are at all viable.

> The “open text” often emphasizes or foregrounds process, either the
> process of the original composition or of subsequent compo­sitions by
> readers

Comment: The standard tenet of [the New Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Criticism) is that the you should not give the author's reading any privilege over other well-thought out readings. Saying that no reading is better than any other takes this to a ridiculous extreme, and I really don't believe that this is what Lyn Hejinian is advocating in her essay.

Comment: no i didn't mean that every reading is as good. i'll edit the question @PeterShor

Comment: Is there anything in her essay that makes you think she is talking about different *goals* in reading rather than different readings?

Comment: i haven't read it for a while, will look for some quotes, thanks @PeterShor

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to say that Lynn Hejinian says that there are multiple readings of an "open text". However, she does not say that all readings would be equally viable or valid. There are two passages in her essay that address this. First, she writes (emphasis added),

> though the  “story” and “tone” of such works may be interpreted differently by different readers, nonetheless the readings differ within definite limits. While word strings are permissive, **they do not license a free-for-all**.

Further down, she approvingly quotes a passage from Umberto Eco's *The Role of the Reader* (emphasis added):

> I call these interpretative moves inferential walks: they are not mere whimsical initiatives on the part of the reader, but are **elicited by discursive structures and foreseen by the whole textual strategy** as indispensable components of the construction.

In other words, due to a text's "discursive strategies" some readings of a text will be more convincing than others. The text will more strongly "resist" interpretations that work against it. For this reason, not all readings will be equally viable.

This is not an unusual position. See for example chapter 4 ("Interpretation") in Terry Eagleton's book *How to Read Literature* (Yale University Press, 2013):

> Literary works may best be seen not as texts with a fixed sense, but as matrices capable of generating a whole range of possible meanings. They do not so much contain meaning as produce it.

However, this does not imply that "anything goes". Eagleton later says,

> There is no single correct interpretation of 'Baa Baa Black Sheep' [a nursery rhyme that Eagleton had discussed earlier in the book], or for that matter of any other literary work. Even so, there are more and less plausible ways of making sense of it. A persuasive reading must take account of the textual evidence, though establishing this evidence itself involves interpretation.

Note that Eagleton, unlike Lynn Hejinian, does not exclude "some contemporary lyric poetry" and "detec­tive fiction", which Hejinian categorises as "closed" types of texts. From the point of view of modern literary theory, Hejinian's category of "closed texts" comes across as a strawman, since theory would not reduce, for example, the meaning of a detective story to just the revelation that the butler did it with the candle stick in the conservatory. Meaning is much more than that.

---

**Note**: This is a response to the [version of the question from 14.01.2019 - 02.08.2020](https://literature.stackexchange.com/revisions/9119/5), which asked, "I just wondered if each different method, way, of reading a text is equally viable." The words "if they are at all viable" were added after this answer was submitted.

Comment: not what "free for all" means: open to everyone -- equally valid for *all*

Comment: @a_person: [free-for-all](https://www.lexico.com/definition/free-for-all): "A disorganized or unrestricted situation or event in which everyone may take part, especially a fight, discussion, or trading market." (*Lexico* dictionary online.)

Comment: exactly -- all readings are equally vlalid, and not "restricted" by the text... can you not see the difference?

Comment: please amend your question to note that "anything goes" does not mean "a few things work"

Comment: @a_person What is your problem? In the first passage I quote from Hijinian's 
essay, she says that readings differ within limits that are defined by 
the words. This implies that readings that move outside these limits 
would be less viable. Did you overlook the word "not" in "they do 
**not** license a free-for-all"? The author does not claim that all  readings are equally valid, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @a_person Where did I say that "anything goes" means "a few things work"? What is there to amend?

Comment: "many readings... each [by which i do mean every] different method, way, of reading a text is equally viable." which you then try to refute: "multiple readings... [but] not all readings are equally valid"

Comment: i.e my 'open text' is not wrong, counter to yours, and does not say anything goes. only that anything that works is as good as anything else that does

Comment: @a_person I have shown by means of two quotes that Hejinian does not consider all readings as equally viable. Where's the support for your interpretation?

Comment: i'm not saying that all readings are valid, i'm saying that all valid readings are equally valid

Comment: @a_person You did not ask in your original question whether Hejinian was saying that all valid readings were equally valid. And she does not appear to say anything about this in her essay. But you still haven't explained why I should "amend" anything in my answer.

Comment: because you misunderstood my question... "many [by which i do not mean every] readings... each different method, way, of reading a text is equally viable."

Comment: i guess i was being unclear... probably cos i just can't think of a "reading", rather than writing about reading [false claims about the text], that is not valid. ?

Comment: @a_person: These are probably too trivial to be really good examples, but I would say that claiming that Emily Dickinson's [*Further in Summer than the Birds*](https://www.emilydickinsonmuseum.org/further-in-summer-than-the-birds-895/) is about cicadas (which people have done), or that her [*The Snow that Never Drifts*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Snow_that_never_drifts_%E2%80%94) is about February, would be invalid.

Comment: hmm, i might disagree.